# Python file to exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I try to convert my python files (By using pyinstaller) into an executable I get the error message:

```
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'System can not access the file')
```

Does anyone know the solution to fix this?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that at the very least includes how you are trying to convert your code into an executable. What command are you executing? What does the folder structure look like? What path are you providing?

Comment: Have you used PyInstaller?

Comment: I used pyinstaller sorry my bad